# C# bubble sort function returning data type not results?? code issue or file set up?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Very new to C# and completely new to C# in VS code. Im not sure if there is an issue with my code or the application file set up, in either case the return value I receive is System.Int32[], not the actual array contents.

I created a console project  - dotnet new console -n "algos"

I added a solution file      - dotnet new sln -n "algorythems_solution"

I added project to solution  - dotnet sln algorythems_solution.sln add ./algos/algos.csproj

To run the program I have used f5 and - dotnet run

```
using System;

namespace algos
{
    class sortingAlgorythems
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int[] test = {-4,5,10,8,-10,-6,-4,-2,-5,3,5,-4,-5,-1,1,6,-7,-6,-7,8};
            int[] sorted = bubbleSort(test);
            Console.WriteLine(sorted.ToString());
        }
        public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] array)
        {
            bool isSorted = false;
            int toValue = array.Length - 1;
            int fromValue = 0;
            while (isSorted == false) 
            {
                isSorted = true;
                int cnt = 0;
                for (int i = fromValue; i < toValue; i++) 
                {
                    if (array[i] > array[i+1])
                    {
                        cnt = i;
                        int temp1 = array[i];
                        int temp2 = array[i+1];
                        array[i] = temp2;
                        array[i+1] = temp1;
                        if (isSorted == true)
                        {
                            isSorted = false;
                            if (i > 0)
                            {
                                fromValue = i -1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                toValue = cnt;
            }
            return array;
        }
    }
}
```

Any insights into what my issue may be are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Array.ToString()` output the type of array. Instead, a loop in `main` to output all of its element by foreach or for would do the work.

Comment: Thanks Louis, that worked just fine.  I was expecting it to work something like python print(array).  When that did not work I added the ToString.  Is there any way to print/show the array directly without the loop in c#?

Comment: You can inherit from certain types and override `ToString`.  You can also use extension methods so that the code is all in one place.  They're quite useful when you can't modify the implementation directly - like when it's not your code.  In fact that's how LINQ works with types defined long before it existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrectly assumed what `ToString()` does. The default behavior is to simply display the type of the object (though it is overridden for many types to display something more useful).

Here's a simple solution for you:

```
        int[] sorted = bubbleSort(test);
        for(int i = 0; i < sorted.Length; ++i)
        {
           Console.WriteLine($"{i}: {sorted[i]}");
        }
```

Comment: Should be `$"{i}: {sorted[i]}"`

Comment: @Zer0: Thank you. As I was writing the answer, something in my head was saying 'You've got something wrong here", but I couldn't put my finger on what. Funny how memory works.

Comment: Thanks for the example, more that I was incorrectly assuming what Console.WriteLine  dose.  I was thinking it would work similarly to pythons print(array).  I take it there is not a way to display the array directly with c#?

Comment: @Dru: Correct, there is nothing inbuilt in the C# language for outputting collections as strings, but fortunately writing an extra loop to do it is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example generic extension method.  Note it must be defined in a `public static class`.

```
public static void WriteToConsole<T>(this IList<T> list)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
    }
}
```

Can be used like this:

```
int[] arr;
arr.WriteToConsole();
```